# DataGridView Cell Backcolor not set

Tags: c#, datagridview, coding-style, backcolor

I have a DataGridView with four columns. The first three are returned back as an array: red, green and blue. All values are between 0 and 255. I've programmatically added a column called "Colour". I'd like the backcolor of this column to reflect the RGB content. 
I can see the rgb data correctly, and using the debugger, the backcolor is being set correctly against the property. I can also set the column's backcolor and it displays correctly. I've tried setting the "Red" cell's backcolor and this doesn't work either.

The below code results in a completely white column.

Here's my code:

```
        DataGridViewColumn DGC = new DataGridViewColumn();
        DGC.Name = "Colour";
        DGC.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
        dgPallette.Columns.Add(DGC);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow DGR in dgPallette.Rows)
        {
            Color cellColor = Color.FromArgb(
                int.Parse(DGR.Cells["Red"].Value.ToString()), 
                int.Parse(DGR.Cells["Green"].Value.ToString()), 
                int.Parse(DGR.Cells["Blue"].Value.ToString()));
            DGR.Cells["Colour"].Style.BackColor = cellColor;
        }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance
Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes I find that setting colours in the DataGridView doesn't work as expected and end up resorting to using the [DataGridView.CellFormatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx) event - this always does the trick, and is fairly straightforward to get your head around.

Often formatting problems arise when the grid is bound to a datasource - especially when you allow sorting.  This event overcomes that.

Comment: Thanks. The contents of the datagrid are dependent on a combobox. I've hooked in the selecteditem change event to call the above code against the new returned array, and the colours are displaying correctly. I've tried calling datagridview.Update() after the code, but the first update isn't happening....

Comment: Thank you very much. I've implemented the CellFormatting event and this seems to have sorted the problem.

Comment: private void dgPallette_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == dgPallette.Columns["Colour"].Index)
            {
                DataGridViewRow DGR = dgPallette.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(
                    int.Parse(DGR.Cells["Red"].Value.ToString()),
                    int.Parse(DGR.Cells["Green"].Value.ToString()),
                    int.Parse(DGR.Cells["Blue"].Value.ToString()));
            }
        }